Android Studio closes all files and collapses file tree
I'm working on a macbook pro m1 cpu, using Android Studio jellyfish.
Each time I'm building my project, all the files in the editor are closed and the "filetree" on the left side collapses completely. Only folders i see then, are app and gradle scripts and I'm not able to even open the app folder. I need to doubleclick on the app folder, open "project structure" then the "filetree" reloads and only then I'm able to open files again.
Android studio is not usable this way, since I need to reopen all the files im working with, after each build...
Does anyone have a solution for this?
btw. I'm using Android view. Project View only shows scratches and consoles and external libs, whereas project files view only shows Extensions and Scratches...
FYI on my macbook pro with m2 pro cpu it works as expected...
I tried reinstalling Android studio, updating OS, reinstalling macOS Sonoma, installing Intel Version of Android Studio, reopening, invalidating caches
I expect the files to stay open after I build.
It seems to be a similiar problem like here:
How stop Android Studio from collapsing (closing) all the directories in "Project Files" pane?
Same goes for this:
Android Studio - running a build collapses all the folders in the Project browser?
But the solutions proposed are not valid in the newer versions of Android Studio. Does anyone have the same Problem? Im running out of ideas.

having same problem with Android Studio Koala

A colleague had the same problem. Apparently a MacOS update removed some permissions for Android Studio. Check if Android Studio has Full Disk Access! This fixed the problem!

It was a nightmare, but I created a new user account on my Mac and now everything works fine. Just wanted to post this here as a possible "solution" for the issue. In case someone knows how something like this can happen, I would really appreciate some more info/ideas.

If anyone is encountering this issue, go to System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Full Disk Access. Make sure Android Studio is full disk access.
